# "Sweep" a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm using a vector to store pointers to objects. In some cases I destroy one or more of these objects (setting the vector spaces to `NULL` after each `delete` call), which are externally selected:

```
for (int i=0; i<form->SelectListBox->Items->Count; i++) {
    if (form->SelectListBox->Selected[i]) {
        delete items[i];
        items[i]=NULL;
    }
}
```

After that, I have erase all `NULL` pointers. This is what I'm doing and it works:

```
ItemVector::iterator it;
while ((it=std::find(items.begin(), items.end(), (MyObjects*)NULL))!=items.end()) {
    items.erase(it);
}
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to "sweep" a vector of pointers? <sup>[1]</sup>

---

<sup>[1]</sup> As you may have guessed, I'm using C++Builder (version 6) and its VCL and try to migrate from using `TList` to using `std::vector` as to reduce static casts (the class `TList` provides a `Pack` method.

Comment: I think the idiom you're looking for is the "erase-remove idiom", see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Erase-Remove I would also recommend using the std::nullptr type which was introduced in C++11 in stead of NULL.

Comment: If possible you should avoid raw pointers in favour of smart pointers. For example you could use boost::ptr_vector<T>, which is designed specifically to contain pointers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your algorithm is O(N²) - if you have 1000 elements in your vector and the first 100 are null, it will run the while loop 100 times, each repositioning up to 999 elements.

In implementation, you would use two iterators, one which you read from and one which you write to. If the read element is null, do not write it, otherwise write it back and increment.

The standard algorithm for doing this is called [`remove_if`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/remove_if.html) and there's detail discussion in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604024/now-to-remove-elements-that-match-a-predicate).

Comment: Great: just what I was looking for. Seems I've to learn more about standard algorithms. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @Wolf It's easy to forget that even if you don't see it being done, that doesn't mean that it is an operation that is O(1).

Comment: @Neil Yes, `remove_if` is O(N). I'm now elaborating a `pack_vector_of_pointers` template function having problems with deducing the predicate parameter type...

Comment: Accepted. The `remove_if` "idiom" reads a bit strange, but the upvotes speak a clear language: I should switch to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the 2nd pass by calling erase as you delete the element.  You need to [convert the index to an iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875103/how-to-erase-element-from-stdvector-by-index) and [be sure you account for the fact that erasing items changes subsequent indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596162/can-you-remove-elements-from-a-stdlist-while-iterating-through-it)

```
int deleted = 0;
for (int i=0; i < Count; i++) {
    if (Selected[i]) {
        delete items[i];
        items.erase(items.begin()+i-deleted++);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, but that calculation looks to be the kind of thing you don't want to maintain.

Comment: @gbjbaanb sure, but isn't it only the `-deleted++` part that causes the confusion? I find this a valid argument, because two code loops for one logical iteration are of course somewhat suspicious.

Comment: `items.begin()+i-deleted++` is nightmarish.  Adding numbers to an iterator is scary at best, not to mention that it is still O(N^2) time.

Comment: @Wolf yup, its the nasty calculation: begin iterator + count - deleted + 1... Little brain get confuse. Don't likey. Will break it one Friday afternoon when it gets refactored to be begin()+i-deleted+1

Comment: The `deleted++` can be moved to a separate line to make it clearer. However, the O(N^2) can't be fixed, so I hereby disown this suggestion.